# how can something be bigger than (unsigned long long) > LONG_MAX?

Tags: c

I found this code in an algorithm I need to update:

```
 if (value > (unsigned long long) LONG_MAX)
```

EDIT: `value` is the result of a division of two `uint64_t` numbers.

I understand that `(unsigned long long) LONG_MAX` is a VERY big number:

```
   #include "stdio.h"
   #include "limits.h"

   int main() {
     unsigned long long ull = (unsigned long long) LONG_MAX;
     printf("%lu",ull);
     return 0;
   }
```

prints `9223372036854775807`

So what I am comparing here? In what case this `if` statement will evaluate to `true`?

Comment: You should use the the `..._MAX` macro that corresponds to your data type. There are e.g `LONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULLONG_MAX`, `UINT64_MAX`. An `unsigned long` value can be greater than `(unsigned long) LONG_MAX` which is intended for `signed long`

Comment: We do not need `float`, `double`, or `unsigned long long` to exceed `LONG_MAX`. Plain `unsigned long suffices`; `ULONG_MAX` is greater than `LONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can something be bigger than (unsigned long long) > LONG_MAX?

Easily.  `LONG MAX` is the maximum value that can be represented as a `long int`.  Converting that to `unsigned long long` does not change its *value*, only its *data type*.  The maximum value that can be represented as an `unsigned long int` is larger on every C implementation you're likely to meet.  The maximum value of `long long int` is larger on some, and the maximum value of `unsigned long long int` is, again, larger on every C implementation you're likely to meet (*much* larger on some).

However, this ...

```
     unsigned long long ull = (unsigned long long) LONG_MAX;
     printf("%lu",ull);
```

... is not a conforming way to investigate the value in question because `%lu` is a formatting directive for type `unsigned long`, not `unsigned long long`.  The `printf` call presented therefore has undefined behavior.

> I found this code in an algorithm I need to update:
>
> ```
>  if (value > (unsigned long long) LONG_MAX)
> ```
>
> EDIT: value is the result of a division of two uint64_t numbers.
>
> [...]
>
> In what case this if statement will
>   evaluate to true?

Supposing that `value` has type `uint64_t`, which is probably the same as `unsigned long long` in your implementation, the condition in that `if` statement will evaluate to true *at least* when the most-significant bit of `value` is set.  If your `long int` is only 32 bits wide, however, then the condition will evaluate to true much more widely than that, because there are many 64-bit integers that are larger than the largest value representable as a signed 32-bit integer.

I would be inclined to guess that the code was indeed written under the assumption that `long int` is 32 bits wide, so that the `if` statement asks a very natural question: "can the result of the previous `uint64_t` division be represented as a `long`?"  In fact, that's what the `if` statement is evaluating in any case, but it makes more sense if `long` is only 32 bits wide, which is typical of 32-bit computers and standard on both 32- and 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 5):

A `float` or `double` can be larger than that.  Appendix Ep5 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states that either type must be able to hold a value at least as large as `1E37` which is a larger value than `LONG_MAX` which must be at least 2147483647:

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by
>   implementation-defined constant expressions with values that are
>   greater than or equal to those shown:
>
> ```
> #define DBL_MAX 1E+37
> #define FLT_MAX 1E+37
> #define LDBL_MAX 1E+37
> ```

So if `value` is either of those types, it could evaluate to true.

EDIT:

Since `value` is a `uint64_t`, whose max value is 18446744073709551615, this can also be larger than `LONG_MAX`.

Comment: oh,I see, thanks! `value` is a result of a division of two ` uint64_t` numbers

Answer (score 3):

`LONG_MAX` is maximum value for a `signed long`. By standard it should be `>= +2147483647` (fits in 32 bit signed)

There's also `ULLONG_MAX` for `unsigned long long`, which is currently most often 18446744073709551615. The standard mandates that to be `>=` than 9223372036854775807

Comment: `LONG_MAX` is _at least_ +2147483647 and it won't be above if `long` is 32 bits wide. `ULLONG_MAX` is _at least_ 18446744073709551615 and `LLONG_MAX` is _at least_ +9223372036854775807 and they won't be larger if `long long` is 64 bits wide.